Are local variables and functions in Kotlin re-created every time a function is called?
Consider this code:
class Foo {
    fun bar() {
        val localVariable = 1

        fun localFunction() {
            // ...
        }

        // Rest of the code
    }
}

Every time I call bar(), will localVariable be 'recreated' and will localFuncion() be 'redefined'? Basically, is it better performance-wise to have both of them in the class scope instead of local scope if I know that I will be calling bar() several times?
I assume that since localVariable is a val (final), maybe its value will either be inlined if possible, otherwise cached between calls to bar() by the compiler. Is this true?

What platform are you targeting? JVM or JS or Native?

JVM, for Android apps

This kind of optimization is so microscopic, if you are worrying about it, this module of your code should be done in JNI. You should prioritize code clarity over micro-optimizations like this in the vast majority of cases.

Another reason not to attempt micro-optimisations is that your code is only the starting point: the JVM's optimiser can transform it completely, and it's likely to do better on code that's clear, simple, and straightforward.  Design well, use the right algorithms and clear code, and don't worry about optimising unless/until you can demonstrate a problem (and even then, measure the effect of your changes).

On Kotlin/JVM, local functions will be compiled to methods of the enclosing class, just like regular instance methods. The local variables captured by the local function will be passed as parameters. So in the compiled binary, there is not much difference between writing a local function and writing an instance method.
Local variables do have their initialisers run, every time you call the enclosing function. In the case of localVariable, this is only two bytecode instructions - pushing the constant 1 (iconst) and storing it in localVariable (istore). I wouldn't worry about performance here.
If the variable initialiser is time-consuming, then you might want to write it as an instance property instead, assuming that this doesn't change the correctness of bar. The initialisers for instance properties will be run every time a new instance of that class is created.
Whether the compiler will inline vals is an implementation detail of the compiler. There are no guarantees.


If the variable initialiser is time-consuming, then you might want to write it as an instance property instead - The only problem I see with this is that sometimes, it just doesn't make sense for localVariable to be a part of the class itself, as opposed to being restricted to the local scope of bar(). But I guess its OK since it doesn't happen all that often, and I'd be willing to tolerate this small pet peeve for the performance improvement gained by making it an instance variable.

